# how to retrieve the values in options of dropdownlist in for loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following html code for select tag:
    
        Apple
        Orange
        Pineapple
        Banana
    
    
I am using the following function for retrieving the values in drop downlist using for loop

```
function mySelectval()
{
    var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < sel ; i++)
    {
        var e = document.getElementById("mySelect").options[i].value;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e;
}
```

when I click on the button I am not getting the values that are in "e"

Comment: Each time through the loop you re-create the `e` variable. It is also scoped to the for-loop - i.e it doesn't exist after the loop is finished. I imagine you're getting 'undefined' as the output? **EDIT**: scratch-that, I can see that the output is the value of the last option, correct?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle  or your HTML code atleast ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function mySelectval()
    {
        var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < sel ; i++)
        {
            var e = document.getElementById("mySelect").options[i].value;

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e +','+ document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mySelectval()
{
    var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length,
    e=[];
    for(var i = 0 ; i < sel ; i++)
    {
        e.push(document.getElementById("mySelect").options[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e.join(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable e is only scoped to the for loop. Set it outside and then make sure you concatenate it.

```
function mySelectval()
{
    var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length;
    var e = ''; //  Set it outside the loop

    for(var i = 0 ; i < sel ; i++)
    {
        // concatenate it
        e += document.getElementById("mySelect").options[i].value + ", ";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e;
}
```